# Create a sharepoint registration page for external users

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, authorization, dynamics-crm

I want to make a sharepoint site where everyone has access to the login page. On the login page, there should be a link to a registration page where new users can register. The emailadress provided must exist in another database (Dynamics CRM 2011) to check if this user can have his own sharepoint username and password. If so, the system must create this user.

What is the best way to implement this?

Maybe important to know is that we are also looking for a single signon for our front office users. Who are using Sharepoint from withing Dynamics CRM 2011. I think we need claims based authentication for this. Or is this possible with FBA too? Because i saw a few implementation for this using fba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to write your own custom fba authentication provider.

Full example is here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/08/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-fba-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

With this you can make your homework and use your own code to authenticate against the CRM

Comment: It's a good article, but it's only providing an page to login for users who are already registered.

Comment: this is the last part. http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1099, you already have the login part and this url shows the registration page part.  Of course there you would replace the code to insert the users on your CRM.